# How to include code from another module in ascidoc?

Tags: java, maven, asciidoc

I am trying to write a documentation for my maven module, using ascidoctor. Now I want to show a code snipped from another module.

Usually I would include code from my module, like that:

```
[source, java]
----
include::{source-code}/main/java/myPackage/mySubPackage/myClass.java[tag=myTag]
----
```

I tried to gain access to the module by using the direct path of my class. But I failed.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the `source-code` attribute? And the path to the file containing the `include` macro?

Comment: I am answering you on wednesday, when I have accsess to my job laptop, again.